# Prevent intercepting of ga.push by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics for tracking custom events, but **how do I prevent intercepting of a GA event by the jQuery event handler**?

Inline notation works fine:

```
<body onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Demo', 'Click'])">
```

When I move this piece of code to separate JavaScript file and use jQuery - it fails:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Demo', 'Click']); // Does not do anything
    console.log(_gaq); // This normally prints out content of GA
    //return true;
});
```

Thoughts?

**Update:** Tracker also works fine if I try to process events from separate JavaScript code, but without jQuery.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.onclick = function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Demo', 'Click']); // This event is getting fired
        console.log(_gaq);
        //return true;
    }
}
```

**What is wrong with jQuery?**

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @apohl : no, there are no any errors, tracker works fine for "onload" event from any place and it works for "click" only when it is called directly from HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is funny and weird at the same time. It seems that I accidentally override GA each time on the `document.ready` event.

1. The weird thing is that I checked whether GA is already initialized, but it seems that it does not work or uses some asynchronous initialization...
2. Funny is that it was enough to move initialization of GA outside the jQuery OnReady event to make everything working.

Was (wrong):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    // ... Some event handling
```

Now (correct):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ... some event handling
```

I am not sure how to explain this, but this fixes my issue ... closed.